# Why this call to AddEventHandler is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection, delegates

I have the following proof of concept classes:

```
    private class SourceMock
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler TestEvent;

        public void Raise()
        {
            if (this.TestEvent != null)
            {
                this.TestEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("S"));
            }
        }
    }

    private class HandlerMock
    {
        public HandlerMock()
        {
        }

        public void PropertyHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then if I do the following it works:

```
    SourceMock sourceMock = new SourceMock();
    HandlerMock handler = new HandlerMock();

    sourceMock.GetType().GetEvent("TestEvent").AddEventHandler(sourceMock, new PropertyChangedEventHandler(handler1.PropertyHandler));
```

But if do the following it does not work:

```
    SourceMock sourceMock = new SourceMock();
    HandlerMock handler = new HandlerMock();

    sourceMock.GetType().GetEvent("TestEvent").AddEventHandler(sourceMock, new EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(handler1.PropertyHandler));
```

because I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type
>   'System.EventHandler`1[System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'.

I want to have a generic class for dealing with events and I cannot use delegates as generic types I have to use EventArgs which imposes me the second syntax (the non-working one).

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

**EDIT: This is what I'm trying to achieve**

I need a class to intercept events and do things before raising them (like counting them, filtering them, reordering them, etc) . Clients will not register to events but will ask this class to register them to the event. The signature I thought is the following one:

```
public class EventHandlerService<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    public void Register(object eventSource, string eventName, EventHandler<T> handler)
}
```

When the event happens the service will call all the registered handlers based on an internal algorithm.

Internally it is working with the EventInfo class and it is not working with EventHandlers not derived from EventHandler thus this question.

Comment: You are simply using the wrong delegate type.   EventHandler<> is a completely unrelated type.  PropertyChangedEventHandler goes back to .NET 1.x, no generics in that version yet.  That they look alike plays no role at all, two different delegate types are never considered identical, even if their signature matches.

Comment: So, is there a way to create a generic class that will receive PropertyChangedEventHandler handlers among other handlers and work with them? Using EventHandler<T> and specifying T as EventArgs did the trick but not for the ones inheriting from EventHandler ...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've added the X part.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate type for event isn't necessary inherited from `EventHandler`/`EventHandler<T>`, as you can see. So, maybe generics here are superfluous:

```
public class EventHandlerService
{
    /// <example>
    /// Use this overload, when delegate type for the event isn't inherited from EventHandler/EventHandler{T}.
    /// <code>
    /// service.Register(someObj, "SomeEvent", new PropertyChangedHandler(TheHandler));
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public void Register(object eventSource, string eventName, Delegate handler)
    {
        // do the work here
    }

    /// <example>
    /// Use this overload, when delegate type for the event is inherited from EventHandler{T}.
    /// <code>
    /// service.Register<FooEventArgs>(someObj, "SomeEvent", TheHandler);
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public void Register<T>(object eventSource, string eventName, EventHandler<T> handler)
        where T : EventArgs
    {
        Register(eventSource, eventName, handler);
    }

    /// <example>
    /// Use this overload, when delegate type for the event is inherited from EventHandler.
    /// <code>
    /// service.Register(someObj, "SomeEvent", TheHandler);
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public void Register(object eventSource, string eventName, EventHandler handler)
    {
        // we need cast here to help compiler to find desired overload
        Register(eventSource, eventName, (Delegate)handler);
    }
}
```

Particular problem from the question can be solved this way:

```
var eventInfo = sourceMock.GetType().GetEvent("TestEvent");
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(sourceMock, Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, handler, "PropertyHandler"));
```

But looks like you don't need to solve it - just remove generics.